# pandas - how to access cell in pandas, equivalent of df[3,4] in R

Tags: indexing, pandas, dataframe

If I have a pandas DataFrame object, how do I simply access a cell?  In R, assuming my data.frame is called df, I can access the 3rd row and 4th column by

```
df[3,4]
```

What is the equivalent in python?

Comment: The correct method to this question (for selecting a specific cell) is to use `df.at[3, 4]` as the [second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28449974/4909087) shows.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

You can use iloc (to get by *position*):

```
df.iloc[3,4]
```

*I recommend reading the [indexing section of the docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html).*

Comment: `.ix()` is more versatile than `.iloc()`

Comment: @smci they do different things. Sometimes you want to get by label (loc), sometimes by position (iloc), sometimes both (ix). Sometimes ix is ambiguous. iloc is faster.

Comment: Andy, `.ix()` is a superset of `.iloc()`, so for the purpose of this question they're equivalent. Wasn't aware of much speed difference.

Comment: @smci Not sure I would say that... e.g. `df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [3, 4]], [1, 0], [1, 0])` try `df.loc[0, 0], df.iloc[0, 0], df.ix[0, 0]`, `ix` is ambiguous for this integer indexed DataFrame - which is why loc and iloc exist. They also act differently when you have a non-unique index (where loc/ix are type unstable).

Comment: @AndyHayden in case of handle float numbers, would `iloc` works as well?

Answer (score 42):

If you want to access the cell based on the column and row labels, use `at`:

```
df.at["Year","Temperature"]
```

This will return the cell intersected by the row "Year" and the column "Temperature".

Comment: Actually the `df.at[ ..., ...]` was the thing I was looking for.