# How to use a tuple to populate data frame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe such as:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(index=[1,2,3,4], columns=[1,2,3,4])
>>> df
     1    2    3    4
1  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
3  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
4  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
>>>
```

And a list of tuples to use as "coordinates". One of the tuples, for example:

```
(2,4)
```

I would like to enter `1` into this position of the data frame:

```
     1    2    3    4
1  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2  NaN  NaN  NaN   1
3  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
4  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pandas - how to access cell in pandas, equivalent of df\[3,4\] in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21393489/pandas-how-to-access-cell-in-pandas-equivalent-of-df3-4-in-r)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
tup = (2,4)
df.loc[tup] = 1
print (df)
     1    2    3    4
1  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2  NaN  NaN  NaN    1
3  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
4  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

Another solution with [`set_value`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_value.html):

```
df.set_value(tup[0], tup[1], 1)
print (df)
     1    2    3    4
1  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2  NaN  NaN  NaN    1
3  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
4  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

Or [`get_loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.get_loc.html) for position of `index` and `columns` values and set to `numpy array` created by [`values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.values.html):

```
df.values[df.index.get_loc(tup[0]), df.columns.get_loc(tup[1])] = 1
print (df)
     1    2    3    4
1  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2  NaN  NaN  NaN    1
3  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
4  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

Comment: That's great. I ended up using the `df.loc` to do this; `for tup in data:
...     df.loc[tup] = 1`