# How do I assign to a new variable the value of a specific column at index 1

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe, row

I have a CSV with the following columns: `STATION, DATE, TEMP`, etc.

I need to assign a value at index 0 of the **DATE** column to a new variable (let's call it first_observation). So, I need to specify the index of the column DATE. The DataFrame is called "**Data"** and the column **"DATE"**.

I tried something like this:

```
    data = pd.read_csv(fp, sep='\s+', skiprows=[1], na_values=['-9999'])
    first_observation = data.loc[idx[0], 'DATE']
```

But it is not working.

The question differs from the answer [pandas - how to access cell in pandas, equivalent of df[3,4] in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21393489/pandas-how-to-access-cell-in-pandas-equivalent-of-df3-4-in-r) since it discusses a bit different terms. My column name is a string and row names are integers. In the other question, this corresponds as the answer:

```
 first_obs = data.at['Column_name', 'Row_name']
```

The same can't apply or I don't know how to apply it in this case where the answer is:

```
first_obs = data['Column_name'][0] - the [0] being the index of the row
```

Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: What is idx? You probably want something like `something = data.at[idx[1], 'DATE']`

Comment: probably something like `first_obs = data['DATE'][1]`? Assuming I understand idx correctly...

Comment: So my mistake, I was under the belief that idx was index. I am trying to assign a value of the DATE column at index 1

Comment: @carousallie That works

Comment: @MatijaKordic just keep in mind that python starts index at 0 so if you're looking for the first row it'll actually be `data['DATE'][0]`

Comment: Thanks, you are correct. I will edit that from the above question.

Answer (score 0):

DataFrame.loc method takes rows as first argument and columns as second argument.

Rows are also represented by index of the DataFrame, and index starts with 0.

So first row or index[0] is represented by [0:1] as the first argument. For the selected column, the second argument is 'DATE'.

Hnece, to get first row element of the 'DATE' column,

`first_observation = data.loc[0:1, 'DATE']` 
can be used.

Note that you have to pass rows first and columns second as arguments for `.loc` and `.at` methods.